# Table border-collapse: mixing settings

Tags: html, formatting, tablelayout

I'd like to have a group of table entries using the `collapse` setting but to have it `separate` from other groups. Do I have to make a new table for each of these "zones"? I tried that and they don't line up. And they don't collapse together the right way when I just apply `border-collapse` on the `th` and `td` in my CSS.

Ascii art time.

```
<!-- table with two rows two columns with first one having colspan=2: -->
┌────────┐
|  abcd  │
├───┬────┤
| a | bc |
└───┴────┘

<!-- Same table, separate looks like this (but more squished because there arent enough unicode table characters for this) -->
┌─────────┐
|  abcd   │
└─────────┘ <-- this bit is squished together
┌───┐┌────┐
| a || bc |
└───┘└────┘
```

And what I want is something like this where I've got arbitrary control of whether they get collapsed or not:

```
<!-- this table is made of two rows. two <td colspan=2> in the first row. four <td> in the second row. The third and fourth ones are to be separate. The rest collapse their borders. -->
┌────────┬─────────────┐
|  abcd  │     efg     |
├───┬────┼─────────────┘  <--- again, here the hh and ijk borders should be separate but rising to fill that space
|   |    |┌──┐┌───────┐
| a | bc ||hh||  ijk  | 
|   |    |└──┘└───────┘     
└───┴────┘
```

where you can see that I've got hh and ijk as clearly `separate`, but the rest are `collapsed` together.

The problem with putting them into zones which are their own tables, is that the tables no longer share alignments. It makes things not line up in the table any more (how could I expect it to?) but it is a deal-breaker because my data will no longer be organized.

Comment: Um, what? You're going to have to be either more specific, or give some kind of visual example, because as-is, I don't know what you want as a final result.

Comment: Yeah. i tried to be unambiguous in my phrasing but this is a task for pictures. Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that isn't possible with a table. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.
I've tried using `margin:` and `cellspacing=` but they both don't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use a second `table`.

Then you would need to remove some borders and use `border-collapse:separate;` and `border-spacing`

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td{
    padding:1em;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td.no_border{
    border-bottom:0;
    border-right:0;
    padding:0;
}

table.separate{
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px;
}

table.separate td{
    border-collapse:separate;
    padding:1em;
    border-spacing:5px;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/k2cN5/

Comment: So with this you just fudge the spacing manually till it looks good?

Comment: That's it @Steven Lu!  I don't think there is any other way.